# Makemigrations django

Tags: django

Суть проблемы: при makemigrations django не видит файлы моделей. Ошибка: No changes detected in app 'app_name'

Структура приложения:

app_name

- models
- a_folder
- - __init__.py
- - models3.py
- __init__.py
- models1.py
- models2.py

Версия джанго 2.2.0, python 3.7.2.

В интернете люди советуют в __init__.py импортировать все модели, и это работает. Но. До этого я создавал приложения, у которых я тоже удалял стандартную models.py, создавал папку models, копировал в неё __init__.py и там создавал свои .py файлы моделей без импортирования их в __init__.py и все прекрасно мигрировалось

---

@m0nte-cr1st0 да,  @Александр первоначально миграций и не было, т.к. приложение новое.

Comment: Правильно пишется `__init__.py`. На всякий случай, если это не опечатка

Comment: Да, в проге init.py файлы c подчёркиваниями. При публикации темы сайт съел мои знаки '_'

Comment: @ЮрийЛуг приложение подключили в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @ЮрийЛуг, поправил отображение

Comment: Вообще "no changes detected in app' - это не ошибка, а уведомление о том, что под программа миграции не обнаружила изменений в моделях для внесения изменений в бд. Вероятно, они были, но она их не видит. Надо знать: почему-то в джанго миграции работают правильно только при удалении старых файлов в папке миграции

Comment: m0nte-cr1st0 да, @Александр первоначально миграций и не было, т.к. приложение новое. т.е. мне нечего удалять

Comment: @ЮрийЛуг, папка миграции проекта пустая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если написана модель, но она нигде не импортируется и не используется, то django и не пройдёт по этой модели и не зафиксирует миграцию о ней. В таком случае, эту модель нужно импортировать в `__init__.py`, потому, что django проходит по всем таким файлам `__init__.py` при запуске сервера.

Если ваша модель уже импортирована, допустим, в класс ModelForm, а эта форма используется в каком-то view, а этот view уже импортирован в каком-либо файле urls.py (а django заходит в urls.py автоматически), то можно считать, что ваша модель видна для django.